# Policy against vs policy towards

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which of the following is correct and why?

> Zero tolerance policy needed **towards attacks** on Indian students in Canada.

or

> Zero tolerance policy needed **against attacks** on Indian students in Canada.

Comment: If you are using it in the sense of "referring to", "towards" could work, but "regarding" would be less ambiguous (policy regarding attacks on Indian students; "toward" could imply a side of the argument).  You can have a policy against attacks.  A zero tolerance policy means that it is against attacks, so if you use "against" again, it becomes a double negative; a zero tolerance policy against attacks would be for attacks.  Using "for" or "towards" would be consistent in direction.  "On" or "regarding" would mean "referring to".

Answer (score 1):

Towards : Google Dictionary

> > preposition
>
> preposition: towards
>
> 1.in the direction of.
>
> "I walked toward(s) the front door"
>
> synonyms: in the direction of, to;
>
> 2.as regards; in relation to.
>
> "he was warm and tender toward her"
>
> synonyms: with regard to, as regards, regarding, in regard to,
>   respecting, in relation to, concerning, about, apropos, vis-à-vis "her
>   attitude toward politics"

You want definition 2. In regards to attacks on students, there needs to be a zero tolerance policy.

**Against** does not mean what you think it does. Of course we are against attacks, but we cannot apply that to what we should do.